# show variable not value ,PHP

Tags: php

I´m trying to create a php file with fopen and fwrite ,inside the php file I want to be exactly the variables ,not the values itself.

Below is the way that i create the php file,but it isn´t show the variables

```
$txt ="
<?php
require '../clases/class.db.php';
require '../clases/class.pagina.php';
$configura = new Pagina();
$nombre = $configura->rescata('web');
$vista = $configura->rescata('vista');
$numero = $configura->rescata('numero');
$secciones = $configura->secciones($numero,$i);
$social = $configura->social();
$carrusel = $configura->slider();
$noticias = $configura->noticias($vista,$i);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.....";
```

My code only show e.g. " = new Pagina();" ,i´d like to show " $configura = new Pagina();" exactly not the value or the call for the class,it will happend when you access to the page.

After that I create and save into a file

```
$myfile = fopen($fichero, "w") or die("No puedo crear la web!!!");     fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: PHP replaces the variable with their values. Enclose the content in single quotes or use [nowdoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a bit confusing but I will try to provide an answer like this.

```
$text = '
<?php
echo " ' . $variable . ' "; ' ;
```

Here you see you have to use ' for php not to parse this part and use . to add a variable (not the name of the variable, but the value).

So try changing you text according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
$txt ='
<?php
require "../clases/class.db.php";
require "../clases/class.pagina.php";
$configura = new Pagina();
$nombre = $configura->rescata("web");
$vista = $configura->rescata("vista");
$numero = $configura->rescata("numero");
$secciones = $configura->secciones($numero,$i);
$social = $configura->social();
$carrusel = $configura->slider();
$noticias = $configura->noticias($vista,$i);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.....';
```

NOWDOC:

```
$txt =<<<'NOW'
<?php
require '../clases/class.db.php';
require '../clases/class.pagina.php';
$configura = new Pagina();
$nombre = $configura->rescata('web');
$vista = $configura->rescata('vista');
$numero = $configura->rescata('numero');
$secciones = $configura->secciones($numero,$i);
$social = $configura->social();
$carrusel = $configura->slider();
$noticias = $configura->noticias($vista,$i);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.....
NOW;
```

Or escape the dollar signs:

```
$txt ="
<?php
require '../clases/class.db.php';
require '../clases/class.pagina.php';
\$configura = new Pagina();
\$nombre = \$configura->rescata('web');
\$vista = \$configura->rescata('vista');
\$numero = \$configura->rescata('numero');
\$secciones = \$configura->secciones(\$numero,\$i);
\$social = \$configura->social();
\$carrusel = \$configura->slider();
\$noticias = \$configura->noticias(\$vista,\$i);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.....";
```